Scenario, where PCA on X(train) and X(test) is not a data leakage
There are countless (re)posts discussing the question of using principal component analysis (PCA) as pre-processing method for the features of a regression/classification problem within a cross-validation (CV). I understand that applying PCA to the entire feature dataset before performing CV leads to data leakage, as the test dataset is not completely independent from the training dataset. This compromises our ability to accurately assess how the model will generalize to fresh and unseen data.
However, there is a certain scenario in which I think this does not hold true but I have not found it to be addressed in any of the countless posts on this topic. I think this may not even be an uncommon scenario:
Let us assume, we want to know the values of a target variable ($Y$) within a specific geographical study area ($G$) e.g. to create a spatial map. The features ($X$) are exhaustively available for $G$, think of e.g. high-dimensional remote sensing features as input for $X$.
We can sample and determine $Y$ at certain locations ($Y(s)$); to predict the unknown $Y(u)$. By doing that, we are able to fit a model ($F$) $F: X(s) -> Y(s)$. Next, we can use the model to predict $Y(u)$ given $X(u)$, where the predicted $\hat{Y}(u)$ = $F(X(u)$). We are only interested in using our model ONCE e.g. to create a map, where $X(u) ⊆ G$.
To get the best $\hat{Y}(u)$ possible we would apply PCA on the whole feature dataset $X(s+u)$ prior to fitting $F$, as we have $X(u)$ available.
Next, we want to check how accurate our $\hat{Y}(u)$ (or $F$) was. Since we do not have further independent samples of $Y$ drawn from $G$, we may use CV.
If we would in our CV apply PCA only on $X(train)$ and project it onto the $X(test)$ would we not get pessimistic results? In our actual pipeline we used PCA on $X(u+s)$, so is there any reason to do it differently in the CV, given that we only want to know how our model generalizes to $X(u)$ given $X(u) ⊆ G$.
Am I somehow wrong in my thinking? What is the name of the underlying concept that differs from the typical case, where we want $F$ to generalize well to fresh and independent samples? Does anyone know of any literature addressing this specific scenario?
